# Why do I still not have the 'curious' badge while my score is 8/5?

Tags: support

Out of curiosity, I've been wondering for a while why I still do not have the 'curious' badge while the requirement was reached and even over-reached, i.e. 8/5. It looks like I've asked 8 questions and received a positive score, which is more than 5, right?

Comment: If I had to guess, it would probably include your deleted questions.

Comment: A "well-received" question might mean +5 or +10 or something (the number might depend on which SE site it's on, explaining why they don't specify an exact number).

Comment: @ThePhoton What I mean with 5 in «More than 5» is the 5 in [what I perceived] the target 5 in the «8/5» that appears in my profile for the Curious badge summary, not the score that makes a well-perceived question. ERRATUM: The site in question is stackoverflow.com . I've just realized I haven't asked my question in the right spot, sorry for the noise :-/ .

Answer (score 2):

See this: [Why I haven't I received the "Curious" badge?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263351/why-i-havent-i-received-the-curious-badge)

It looks like deleted questions count against you, and only mods can track that.

Keep answering questions and you'll get it eventually

Comment: I think I get it, I might have deleted some of my own questions, which plays against me. What I don't understand is why *answering* questions will get me there?